# Swift - How to share app link as in the App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share my app using `UIActivityViewController` but I can't reproduce the same effect as when I share an app from the App Store, meaning :

When I clicked the share button in the App Store I have something that looks like this :

[image]

But when I try to share my app I have this :

[image]

The code that I used was :

```
if let logo = UIImage(named: "myLogo"), let websiteURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/idxxxxxxxxxx") {
   let objectsToShare = ["My App Name", websiteURL, logo] as [Any]
   let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: [])
   if let popoverController = activityVC.popoverPresentationController {
      popoverController.sourceView = self.view
      popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
   }
   present(activityVC, animated: true)
}
```

The `if let popoverController = ...` loop is for preventing a crash when using iPads.

What do I have to change in order to have the effect as the App Store? (to have an image with a title and a subtitle)

Moreover, once I share the app with `Messages` for instance, this is the difference :

[image]
[image]

How can I have the same effect? (A single image with the title and subtitle, an as a bonus, a video). I'm not sure if this is an iOS 13 problem, since all similar questions don't have the same app sharing popover.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the new `LinkPresentation` framework.

Which essentially involves UIActivityItemSource conformance then retrieving the metadata that will encompass the Activity View and the data you are sharing. Data can be retrieved locally or downloaded.

```
ExampleController: UIViewController { 
    var metadata: LPLinkMetadata?
    func share() {
        let activityView = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityView, animated: true)
    }
    ...
}

extension ExampleController: UIActivityItemSource {

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return metadata
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return metadata
    }

    func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
        metadata.title = "Title"
        metadata.originalURL = URL(string: "Description")
        metadata.url = metadata.originalURL
        // Using a locally stored item
        metadata.iconProvider = NSItemProvider(object: UIImage(named: "image")!)
        metadata.imageProvider = NSItemProvider.init(contentsOf:
        Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "JPG"))
        return metadata
    }
}
```

Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsource/3144571-activityviewcontrollerlinkmetada

WWDC Presentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/262/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your implementation, and I can see the image and the title appearing in the modal presentation, but the activity types are blank, ie, I cannot share the app (iMessages, Airdrop, etc.. are not here). Maybe is because I did modify a little bit your code. I had to use optional binding in `activityViewControllerLinkMetadata` and I do have `Expression implicitly coerced from 'LPLinkMetadata?' to 'Any'` in `activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem`

Comment: but this does only work for iMessages, right? Not in e.g. WhatsApp, Slack?

Answer (score 1):

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
```

You can use this.